# CCSprite overrite on scene cocos2d-iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

[image]My App is generating sceenshoot of my game.and when i scale up my sceenshoot(CCSprite), other controls like  CCMenu doesn't work.I guess CCSprite(screeenshoot) overrite on my scene.

How to control my CCMenu while CCSprite Scales Down. ?!

```
here is my code 

- (void) showGameOver
 {
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    appDelegate.screenshootimage = [director screenshotUIImage];

    imgsprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:appDelegate.screenshootimage.CGImage key:@"spriteKey"];

    if(flagRescale == false)
    {
           imgsprite.scaleX = 0.40;
           imgsprite.scaleY = 0.40;
           flagRescale = true;
    }

    CCMenuItemImage *image = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:imgsprite selectedSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(imgAction)];

    image.position = ccp(40, 50);
    imageMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:image, nil];
    [self addChild:imageMenu];

    menu_.visible = true;
    menu_.position = ccp(windowCenter_.x, windowCenter_.y - 70);
    lblGameOver.visible = true;
    lblGameOver.position = ccp(windowCenter_.x, windowCenter_.y + 50);
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
}
-(void)imgAction
{
    if(flagRescale == TRUE)
    {
        imgsprite.scaleX = 0.7;
        imgsprite.scaleY = 0.7;
        flagRescale=false;
    }
    else
    {
        imgsprite.scaleX = 0.4;
        imgsprite.scaleY = 0.4;
        flagRescale=true;

    }
}
```

Comment: what's a sceenshoot? and what are you trying to do? I don't understand the question, maybe you need to scale the menu along with the sprites?

Comment: Screenhoot is nothing but an image which has been put in CCSprite.
and that Sprite has been put in CCMenu.So,when i tab on that CCSprite(menu) my CCSprite should scale Up.and once again if i tab on CCSprite my CCSprite should scale down..Which works Perfect...

But the tab action should perform only on CCMenu not on other controls.while it does.Hence,my other controls doesn't work.

Comment: here when i tab on that small CCSprite it Scales UP but other CCMenu like PAUSE,SOUND etc doesn't work.It should work.